# How to find out why my query on postgreSQL is locked?

Tags: postgresql

I have a query which I run it on my postgreSQL every 30 minutes and I expect postgresSQL to answer me in about 1 second (based on the size of the DB table). Almost all times I receive the query response in the expected time (~1 second). But sometimes I don't receive the answer and I don't receive anything! I mean I need to wait forever for that query. In the other words it seems that postgresSQL waits for something else to finish and then answering my query.

The question is that how I can find out why postgreSQL doesn't answer my query?

I tried to look at pg_stat_activity and following is the result (check 4th row in the following table):

```
 datid | datname  |  pid  | usesysid | usename  |          backend_start           |            xact_start            |           query_start            |           state_change           | wait_event_type |     wait_event      | state  | backend_xid | backend_xmin |                                                                                              query                                                                                              |    backend_type     
-------+----------+-------+----------+----------+----------------------------------+----------------------------------+----------------------------------+----------------------------------+-----------------+---------------------+--------+-------------+--------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------
       |          | 25038 |          |          | 2018-07-26 17:42:31.417755+04:30 |                                  |                                  |                                  | Activity        | AutoVacuumMain      |        |             |              |                                                                                                                                                                                                 | autovacuum launcher
       |          | 25040 |       10 | postgres | 2018-07-26 17:42:31.417821+04:30 |                                  |                                  |                                  | Activity        | LogicalLauncherMain |        |             |              |                                                                                                                                                                                                 | background worker
 16385 | analysis | 36912 |       10 | postgres | 2018-07-26 20:16:13.393578+04:30 | 2018-07-26 20:48:37.738759+04:30 | 2018-07-26 20:48:37.738759+04:30 | 2018-07-26 20:48:37.738764+04:30 |                 |                     | active |             |       116475 | select datid,datname,pid,usesysid,usename,backend_start,xact_start,query_start,state_change,wait_event_type,wait_event,state,backend_xid,backend_xmin,query,backend_type from pg_stat_activity; | client backend
 16385 | analysis |  9427 |       10 | postgres | 2018-07-26 19:34:37.109833+04:30 | 2018-07-26 19:35:08.502592+04:30 | 2018-07-26 19:35:08.502592+04:30 | 2018-07-26 19:35:08.502596+04:30 |                 |                     | active |      116475 |       116470 | update dns as origdns set address = (select address from dns where name = origdns.value limit 1) where type = 'cname' and address is null;                                                      | client backend
       |          | 25036 |          |          | 2018-07-26 17:42:31.410811+04:30 |                                  |                                  |                                  | Activity        | BgWriterMain        |        |             |              |                                                                                                                                                                                                 | background writer
       |          | 25035 |          |          | 2018-07-26 17:42:31.41015+04:30  |                                  |                                  |                                  | Activity        | CheckpointerMain    |        |             |              |                                                                                                                                                                                                 | checkpointer
       |          | 25037 |          |          | 2018-07-26 17:42:31.411034+04:30 |                                  |                                  |                                  | Activity        | WalWriterMain       |        |             |              |                                                                                                                                                                                                 | walwriter
(7 rows)
```

As you see above, the 4th query started at 19:35:08 and after about 1hour and 20 minutes I didn't received any response.

I also checked the postgreSQL log in the query time:

```
2018-07-26 19:28:07.371 +0430 [32528] analysis@followdns WARNING:  there is already a transaction in progress
2018-07-26 19:31:08.126 +0430 [19065] analysis@followdns WARNING:  there is already a transaction in progress
2018-07-26 19:33:07.468 +0430 [8837] analysis@followdns WARNING:  there is already a transaction in progress
2018-07-26 19:36:07.137 +0430 [36325] analysis@followdns WARNING:  there is already a transaction in progress
2018-07-26 19:39:07.497 +0430 [22791] analysis@followdns WARNING:  there is already a transaction in progress
2018-07-26 19:42:07.434 +0430 [9232] analysis@followdns WARNING:  there is already a transaction in progress
2018-07-26 19:45:07.707 +0430 [36181] analysis@followdns WARNING:  there is already a transaction in progress
2018-07-26 19:47:07.375 +0430 [22590] analysis@followdns WARNING:  there is already a transaction in progress
2018-07-26 19:50:07.250 +0430 [9076] analysis@followdns WARNING:  there is already a transaction in progress
2018-07-26 19:53:07.416 +0430 [36104] analysis@followdns WARNING:  there is already a transaction in progress
2018-07-26 19:56:08.399 +0430 [23818] analysis@followdns WARNING:  there is already a transaction in progress
2018-07-26 19:58:07.130 +0430 [10272] analysis@followdns WARNING:  there is already a transaction in progress
2018-07-26 20:01:08.183 +0430 [37180] analysis@followdns WARNING:  there is already a transaction in progress
2018-07-26 20:03:07.061 +0430 [23597] analysis@followdns WARNING:  there is already a transaction in progress
2018-07-26 20:06:07.283 +0430 [10160] analysis@followdns WARNING:  there is already a transaction in progress
2018-07-26 20:09:07.701 +0430 [37102] analysis@followdns WARNING:  there is already a transaction in progress
2018-07-26 20:11:08.053 +0430 [23514] analysis@followdns WARNING:  there is already a transaction in progress
2018-07-26 20:14:08.538 +0430 [9960] analysis@followdns WARNING:  there is already a transaction in progress
2018-07-26 20:16:07.602 +0430 [36884] analysis@followdns WARNING:  there is already a transaction in progress
2018-07-26 20:19:07.282 +0430 [23344] analysis@followdns WARNING:  there is already a transaction in progress
2018-07-26 20:22:07.418 +0430 [9796] analysis@followdns WARNING:  there is already a transaction in progress
2018-07-26 20:25:07.797 +0430 [36698] analysis@followdns WARNING:  there is already a transaction in progress
2018-07-26 20:28:07.991 +0430 [23137] analysis@followdns WARNING:  there is already a transaction in progress
2018-07-26 20:31:07.548 +0430 [9587] analysis@followdns WARNING:  there is already a transaction in progress
2018-07-26 20:34:07.893 +0430 [36483] analysis@followdns WARNING:  there is already a transaction in progress
2018-07-26 20:37:07.364 +0430 [22917] analysis@followdns WARNING:  there is already a transaction in progress
2018-07-26 20:40:09.849 +0430 [9401] analysis@followdns WARNING:  there is already a transaction in progress
2018-07-26 20:43:07.694 +0430 [36307] analysis@followdns WARNING:  there is already a transaction in progress
2018-07-26 20:46:07.424 +0430 [22741] analysis@followdns WARNING:  there is already a transaction in progress
2018-07-26 20:49:07.818 +0430 [9191] analysis@followdns WARNING:  there is already a transaction in progress
2018-07-26 20:52:07.221 +0430 [36097] analysis@followdns WARNING:  there is already a transaction in progress
```

FYI:

Service Status: (**Why tasks, memory and CPU are zero?**)

```
mysystem:~$ sudo service postgresql status 
[sudo] password for username: 
● postgresql.service - PostgreSQL RDBMS
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/postgresql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (exited) since Thu 2018-07-26 17:42:33 +0430; 3h 12min ago
  Process: 25054 ExecStart=/bin/true (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 25054 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Tasks: 0
   Memory: 0B
      CPU: 0
   CGroup: /system.slice/postgresql.service

Jul 26 17:42:33 User systemd[1]: Starting PostgreSQL RDBMS...
Jul 26 17:42:33 User systemd[1]: Started PostgreSQL RDBMS.
```

Listening ports:

```
mysystem:~$ sudo netstat -natp | grep -i post
extract_h  8990     root    9u  IPv4 33879493      0t0  TCP localhost:50888->localhost:postgresql (ESTABLISHED)
postgres   8997 postgres   11u  IPv6 31906717      0t0  UDP localhost:57751->localhost:57751 
postgres   8997 postgres   12u  IPv4 33881503      0t0  TCP localhost:postgresql->localhost:50888 (ESTABLISHED)
postgres   9427 postgres   11u  IPv6 31906717      0t0  UDP localhost:57751->localhost:57751 
postgres  25033 postgres    6u  IPv6 31850266      0t0  TCP localhost:postgresql (LISTEN)
postgres  25033 postgres    7u  IPv4 31850267      0t0  TCP localhost:postgresql (LISTEN)
postgres  25033 postgres   11u  IPv6 31906717      0t0  UDP localhost:57751->localhost:57751 
postgres  25035 postgres   11u  IPv6 31906717      0t0  UDP localhost:57751->localhost:57751 
postgres  25036 postgres   11u  IPv6 31906717      0t0  UDP localhost:57751->localhost:57751 
postgres  25037 postgres   11u  IPv6 31906717      0t0  UDP localhost:57751->localhost:57751 
postgres  25038 postgres   11u  IPv6 31906717      0t0  UDP localhost:57751->localhost:57751 
postgres  25039 postgres   11u  IPv6 31906717      0t0  UDP localhost:57751->localhost:57751 
postgres  25040 postgres   11u  IPv6 31906717      0t0  UDP localhost:57751->localhost:57751
```

Note that I can do other queries on the same table of this database:

```
analysis=# select count(*) from dns;
  count  
---------
 2073805
(1 row)

analysis=# select count(*) from dns where type = 'cname' and address is null;
 count 
-------
 46539
(1 row)

analysis=#
```

PG_LOCKS:

```
analysis=# SELECT  * FROM pg_locks;
   locktype    | database | relation | page | tuple | virtualxid | transactionid | classid | objid  | objsubid | virtualtransaction |  pid  |        mode         | granted | fastpath 
---------------+----------+----------+------+-------+------------+---------------+---------+--------+----------+--------------------+-------+---------------------+---------+----------
 relation      |   171525 |   212563 |      |       |            |               |         |        |          | 6/1041             | 35517 | AccessShareLock     | t       | t
 relation      |   171525 |   212562 |      |       |            |               |         |        |          | 6/1041             | 35517 | AccessShareLock     | t       | t
 relation      |   171525 |   212561 |      |       |            |               |         |        |          | 6/1041             | 35517 | AccessShareLock     | t       | t
 relation      |   171525 |   212560 |      |       |            |               |         |        |          | 6/1041             | 35517 | AccessShareLock     | t       | t
 relation      |   171525 |   212559 |      |       |            |               |         |        |          | 6/1041             | 35517 | AccessShareLock     | t       | t
 relation      |   171525 |   212558 |      |       |            |               |         |        |          | 6/1041             | 35517 | AccessShareLock     | t       | t
 relation      |   171525 |   212557 |      |       |            |               |         |        |          | 6/1041             | 35517 | AccessShareLock     | t       | t
 relation      |   171525 |   212550 |      |       |            |               |         |        |          | 6/1041             | 35517 | AccessShareLock     | t       | t
 virtualxid    |          |          |      |       | 6/1041     |               |         |        |          | 6/1041             | 35517 | ExclusiveLock       | t       | t
 relation      |    16385 |    11577 |      |       |            |               |         |        |          | 4/1495             |  8794 | AccessShareLock     | t       | t
 virtualxid    |          |          |      |       | 4/1495     |               |         |        |          | 4/1495             |  8794 | ExclusiveLock       | t       | t
 relation      |    16385 |   213857 |      |       |            |               |         |        |          | 5/850              |  9427 | AccessShareLock     | t       | t
 relation      |    16385 |   213857 |      |       |            |               |         |        |          | 5/850              |  9427 | RowExclusiveLock    | t       | t
 relation      |    16385 |   213856 |      |       |            |               |         |        |          | 5/850              |  9427 | AccessShareLock     | t       | t
 relation      |    16385 |   213856 |      |       |            |               |         |        |          | 5/850              |  9427 | RowExclusiveLock    | t       | t
 relation      |    16385 |   213855 |      |       |            |               |         |        |          | 5/850              |  9427 | AccessShareLock     | t       | t
 relation      |    16385 |   213855 |      |       |            |               |         |        |          | 5/850              |  9427 | RowExclusiveLock    | t       | t
 relation      |    16385 |   213854 |      |       |            |               |         |        |          | 5/850              |  9427 | AccessShareLock     | t       | t
 relation      |    16385 |   213854 |      |       |            |               |         |        |          | 5/850              |  9427 | RowExclusiveLock    | t       | t
 relation      |    16385 |   213853 |      |       |            |               |         |        |          | 5/850              |  9427 | AccessShareLock     | t       | t
 relation      |    16385 |   213853 |      |       |            |               |         |        |          | 5/850              |  9427 | RowExclusiveLock    | t       | t
 relation      |    16385 |   213847 |      |       |            |               |         |        |          | 5/850              |  9427 | AccessShareLock     | t       | t
 relation      |    16385 |   213847 |      |       |            |               |         |        |          | 5/850              |  9427 | RowExclusiveLock    | t       | t
 virtualxid    |          |          |      |       | 5/850      |               |         |        |          | 5/850              |  9427 | ExclusiveLock       | t       | t
 virtualxid    |          |          |      |       | 3/5845     |               |         |        |          | 3/5845             | 35522 | ExclusiveLock       | t       | t
 relation      |   171525 |   215376 |      |       |            |               |         |        |          | 6/1041             | 35517 | AccessExclusiveLock | t       | f
 transactionid |          |          |      |       |            |        116819 |         |        |          | 6/1041             | 35517 | ExclusiveLock       | t       | f
 relation      |   171525 |   215371 |      |       |            |               |         |        |          | 6/1041             | 35517 | AccessShareLock     | t       | f
 relation      |   171525 |   215371 |      |       |            |               |         |        |          | 6/1041             | 35517 | RowExclusiveLock    | t       | f
 relation      |   171525 |   215371 |      |       |            |               |         |        |          | 6/1041             | 35517 | AccessExclusiveLock | t       | f
 transactionid |          |          |      |       |            |        116475 |         |        |          | 5/850              |  9427 | ExclusiveLock       | t       | f
 object        |        0 |          |      |       |            |               |    1260 |  16384 |        0 | 6/1041             | 35517 | AccessShareLock     | t       | f
 relation      |   171525 |   215374 |      |       |            |               |         |        |          | 6/1041             | 35517 | ShareLock           | t       | f
 object        |   171525 |          |      |       |            |               |    2615 | 215369 |        0 | 6/1041             | 35517 | AccessShareLock     | t       | f
 page          |   171525 |   212562 |  822 |       |            |               |         |        |          | 6/1041             | 35517 | SIReadLock          | t       | f
 page          |   171525 |   212562 |  814 |       |            |               |         |        |          | 6/1041             | 35517 | SIReadLock          | t       | f
 page          |   171525 |   212562 |  812 |       |            |               |         |        |          | 6/1041             | 35517 | SIReadLock          | t       | f
 relation      |   171525 |   212558 |      |       |            |               |         |        |          | 6/1041             | 35517 | SIReadLock          | t       | f
 page          |   171525 |   212562 |  825 |       |            |               |         |        |          | 6/1041             | 35517 | SIReadLock          | t       | f
 page          |   171525 |   212562 |  824 |       |            |               |         |        |          | 6/1041             | 35517 | SIReadLock          | t       | f
 relation      |   171525 |   212561 |      |       |            |               |         |        |          | 6/1041             | 35517 | SIReadLock          | t       | f
 relation      |   171525 |   212550 |      |       |            |               |         |        |          | 6/1041             | 35517 | SIReadLock          | t       | f
 page          |   171525 |   212562 |  816 |       |            |               |         |        |          | 6/1041             | 35517 | SIReadLock          | t       | f
 page          |   171525 |   212562 |  826 |       |            |               |         |        |          | 6/1041             | 35517 | SIReadLock          | t       | f
 page          |   171525 |   212562 |  818 |       |            |               |         |        |          | 6/1041             | 35517 | SIReadLock          | t       | f
 page          |   171525 |   212562 |  828 |       |            |               |         |        |          | 6/1041             | 35517 | SIReadLock          | t       | f
 page          |   171525 |   212562 |  827 |       |            |               |         |        |          | 6/1041             | 35517 | SIReadLock          | t       | f
 page          |   171525 |   212562 |  823 |       |            |               |         |        |          | 6/1041             | 35517 | SIReadLock          | t       | f
 relation      |   171525 |   212559 |      |       |            |               |         |        |          | 6/1041             | 35517 | SIReadLock          | t       | f
 page          |   171525 |   212562 |  821 |       |            |               |         |        |          | 6/1041             | 35517 | SIReadLock          | t       | f
 page          |   171525 |   212562 |  815 |       |            |               |         |        |          | 6/1041             | 35517 | SIReadLock          | t       | f
 page          |   171525 |   212562 |  817 |       |            |               |         |        |          | 6/1041             | 35517 | SIReadLock          | t       | f
 page          |   171525 |   212562 |  829 |       |            |               |         |        |          | 6/1041             | 35517 | SIReadLock          | t       | f
 page          |   171525 |   212562 |  819 |       |            |               |         |        |          | 6/1041             | 35517 | SIReadLock          | t       | f
 page          |   171525 |   212562 |  813 |       |            |               |         |        |          | 6/1041             | 35517 | SIReadLock          | t       | f
 page          |   171525 |   212562 |  820 |       |            |               |         |        |          | 6/1041             | 35517 | SIReadLock          | t       | f
(56 rows)

analysis=#
```

**--------------------**

Update:

I checked `htop` output to see if the process with `pid = 9427` (the process of that weird query) consuming CPU or not, and it uses 100% of CPU for about 3 hours!

And I also check the process with `Strace`:

```
mysystem:~$ sudo strace -p 9427
strace: Process 9427 attached
strace: [ Process PID=9427 runs in x32 mode. ]
strace: [ Process PID=9427 runs in 64 bit mode. ]
lseek(24, 0, SEEK_END)                  = 233725952
lseek(24, 0, SEEK_END)                  = 233725952
lseek(24, 0, SEEK_END)                  = 233725952
lseek(24, 0, SEEK_END)                  = 233725952
kill(25036, SIGUSR1)                    = 0
lseek(30, 102711296, SEEK_SET)          = 102711296
read(30, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0L\3p\6\360\37\4 \0\0\0\0p\2060\0\320\237@\0"..., 8192) = 8192
lseek(24, 0, SEEK_END)                  = 233725952
lseek(24, 0, SEEK_END)                  = 233725952
lseek(24, 0, SEEK_END)                  = 233725952
lseek(24, 0, SEEK_END)                  = 233725952
lseek(24, 0, SEEK_END)                  = 233725952
lseek(24, 0, SEEK_END)                  = 233725952
lseek(24, 0, SEEK_END)                  = 233725952
lseek(24, 0, SEEK_END)                  = 233725952
lseek(24, 0, SEEK_END)                  = 233725952
lseek(24, 0, SEEK_END)                  = 233725952
lseek(24, 0, SEEK_END)                  = 233725952
lseek(24, 0, SEEK_END)                  = 233725952
lseek(24, 0, SEEK_END)                  = 233725952
lseek(24, 0, SEEK_END)                  = 233725952
lseek(24, 0, SEEK_END)                  = 233725952
lseek(24, 0, SEEK_END)                  = 233725952
lseek(24, 0, SEEK_END)                  = 233725952
open("base/16385/229351_fsm", O_RDWR)   = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
lseek(30, 0, SEEK_END)                  = 109174784
kill(25036, SIGUSR1)                    = 0
write(30, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 8192) = 8192
lseek(30, 102719488, SEEK_SET)          = 102719488
read(30, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\350\2\0\6\360\37\4 \0\0\0\0\0\206@\0\330\2370\0"..., 8192) = 8192
lseek(24, 0, SEEK_END)                  = 233725952
lseek(24, 0, SEEK_END)                  = 233725952
lseek(24, 0, SEEK_END)                  = 233725952
lseek(24, 0, SEEK_END)                  = 233725952
lseek(24, 0, SEEK_END)                  = 233725952
lseek(24, 0, SEEK_END)                  = 233725952
lseek(24, 0, SEEK_END)                  = 233725952
open("base/16385/229352_fsm", O_RDWR)   = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
lseek(31, 0, SEEK_END)                  = 63250432
kill(25036, SIGUSR1)                    = 0
write(31, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 8192) = 8192
lseek(24, 0, SEEK_END)                  = 233725952
lseek(24, 0, SEEK_END)                  = 233725952
lseek(24, 0, SEEK_END)                  = 233725952
lseek(24, 0, SEEK_END)                  = 233725952
lseek(24, 0, SEEK_END)                  = 233725952
open("base/16385/229351_fsm", O_RDWR)   = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
lseek(30, 0, SEEK_END)                  = 109182976
kill(25036, SIGUSR1)                    = 0
write(30, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 8192) = 8192
lseek(30, 102727680, SEEK_SET)          = 102727680
read(30, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\300\2\370\5\360\37\4 \0\0\0\0\370\205P\0\320\237@\0"..., 8192) = 8192
lseek(24, 0, SEEK_END)                  = 233725952
lseek(24, 0, SEEK_END)                  = 233725952
lseek(24, 0, SEEK_END)                  = 233725952
lseek(24, 0, SEEK_END)                  = 233725952
lseek(24, 0, SEEK_END)                  = 233725952
lseek(24, 0, SEEK_END)                  = 233725952
lseek(24, 0, SEEK_END)                  = 233725952
lseek(24, 0, SEEK_END)                  = 233725952
lseek(24, 0, SEEK_END)                  = 233725952
lseek(24, 0, SEEK_END)                  = 233725952
lseek(24, 0, SEEK_END)                  = 233725952
lseek(24, 0, SEEK_END)                  = 233725952
lseek(24, 0, SEEK_END)                  = 233725952
lseek(24, 0, SEEK_END)                  = 233725952
lseek(24, 0, SEEK_END)                  = 233725952
lseek(24, 0, SEEK_END)                  = 233725952
kill(25036, SIGUSR1)                    = 0
write(24, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 8192) = 8192
lseek(24, 0, SEEK_END)                  = 233734144
lseek(24, 0, SEEK_END)                  = 233734144
lseek(24, 0, SEEK_END)                  = 233734144
lseek(24, 0, SEEK_END)                  = 233734144
lseek(24, 0, SEEK_END)                  = 233734144
lseek(24, 0, SEEK_END)                  = 233734144
lseek(24, 0, SEEK_END)                  = 233734144
lseek(24, 0, SEEK_END)                  = 233734144
lseek(24, 0, SEEK_END)                  = 233734144
lseek(24, 0, SEEK_END)                  = 233734144
lseek(24, 0, SEEK_END)                  = 233734144
lseek(24, 0, SEEK_END)                  = 233734144
lseek(24, 0, SEEK_END)                  = 233734144
lseek(24, 0, SEEK_END)                  = 233734144
lseek(24, 0, SEEK_END)                  = 233734144
lseek(24, 0, SEEK_END)                  = 233734144
lseek(24, 0, SEEK_END)                  = 233734144
lseek(24, 0, SEEK_END)                  = 233734144
lseek(24, 0, SEEK_END)                  = 233734144
lseek(24, 0, SEEK_END)                  = 233734144
lseek(24, 0, SEEK_END)                  = 233734144
lseek(24, 0, SEEK_END)                  = 233734144
lseek(24, 0, SEEK_END)                  = 233734144
lseek(24, 0, SEEK_END)                  = 233734144
lseek(24, 0, SEEK_END)                  = 233734144
lseek(24, 0, SEEK_END)                  = 233734144
lseek(24, 0, SEEK_END)                  = 233734144
lseek(24, 0, SEEK_END)                  = 233734144
lseek(24, 0, SEEK_END)                  = 233734144
lseek(24, 0, SEEK_END)                  = 233734144
lseek(24, 0, SEEK_END)                  = 233734144
lseek(24, 0, SEEK_END)                  = 233734144
lseek(24, 0, SEEK_END)                  = 233734144
lseek(24, 0, SEEK_END)                  = 233734144
lseek(24, 0, SEEK_END)                  = 233734144
lseek(24, 0, SEEK_END)                  = 233734144
lseek(24, 0, SEEK_END)                  = 233734144
open("base/16385/229349_fsm", O_RDWR)   = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
lseek(25, 0, SEEK_END)                  = 69246976
kill(25036, SIGUSR1)                    = 0
write(25, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 8192) = 8192
lseek(24, 0, SEEK_END)                  = 233734144
lseek(24, 0, SEEK_END)                  = 233734144
lseek(24, 0, SEEK_END)                  = 233734144
lseek(24, 0, SEEK_END)                  = 233734144
lseek(24, 0, SEEK_END)                  = 233734144
lseek(24, 0, SEEK_END)                  = 233734144
kill(25036, SIGUSR1)                    = 0
write(24, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 8192) = 8192
lseek(24, 0, SEEK_END)                  = 233742336
lseek(24, 0, SEEK_END)                  = 233742336
lseek(24, 0, SEEK_END)                  = 233742336
lseek(24, 0, SEEK_END)                  = 233742336
lseek(24, 0, SEEK_END)                  = 233742336
```

Comment: Note that I can also insert and delete data into/from this table!

Comment: Doesn't look like a lock. Is the backend process 9427 consuming CPU? You can use `strace` and `perf` to see what's going on.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Yes, it using 99-100% of CPU for hours!!

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I added `strace` output to question.

Comment: Can you use `lsof` to find out what file corresponds to file descriptor 24? And consult `pg_class` what relation has that `relfilenode`? If it is actually an endless loop, one possibility is data corruption. Can you dump/restore the database elsewhere and see if you can reproduce the problem?